# Triggering an automation shortcut on iPhone when a call is picked up

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcut, automation, call

I would like to run an automation or a shortcut every time I pick up an incoming call or dial an outgoing call. What is the trigger I should use? Does such kind of a trigger even exist?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature is not available on iPhone and iOS ecosystem.